# Como inserir String do res/string no array String[]{};

Tags: java, android

Estou tentando colocar minhas Strings em um array para usar no adapter e não consigo.
estou fazendo assim:

```
String cores[] = String[]{getString(R.string.cor1), getString(R.string.cor1)};
```

mas com certeza não é o jeito certo. Como fazer?

Comment: Emerson, você pode criar um array de `String` dentro do resource. Fica uma solução melhor que recuperar item a item e adicionar a um array. Dê uma olhada em http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode declarar um array de String no arquivo array.xml (dentro do diretório values):

```
<string-array name="cores">
    <item>@string/cor1</item>
    <item>@string/cor2</item>
</string-array>
```

Depois crie um array de Strings em sua Activity:

```
String[] cores = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cores);
```

E por fim coloque esta String em seu ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, cores);

ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro criar uma lista de String

```
List<String> cores = new ArrayList<String>();
cores.add(getString(R.string.cor1));
cores.add(getString(R.string.cor1));
```

Comment: então @Helder, eu posso usar assim? `ArrayAdapterItem adapter = new ArrayAdapterItem(this, R.layout.list_view_row_item, cores);`

Answer (score 2):

Apenas para deixar uma referência correta sobre *Arrays* em Java (que não cabe num comentário), a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) define os seguintes modos de inicialização:

## Array vazio com `new`

```java
int[] anArray = new int[10];
anArray[0] = 100;
anArray[1] = 200;
...
```

A primeira linha, com o `new`, simplesmente aloca 10 espaços para o array. As linhas seguintes colocam valores.

## Array preenchido com `new`

Em casos onde é necessário passar um array como parâmetro, podemos criar e já inicializar da seguinte forma:

```java
metodoQueRecebeParametro( new String[] { "Olá", "Mundo" } );
```

## Array preechido na declaração

Quando estamos declarando um array, podemos inicializá-lo de forma simples, assim:

```java
int[] anArray = { 
    100, 200, 300,
    400, 500, 600, 
    700, 800, 900, 1000
};
```

Note que não há `new`, apenas as chaves com os valores dentro.

Isso pode ser feito até com arrays multidimensionais:

```java
String[][] names = {
    {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. "},
    {"Smith", "Jones"}
};
```

## Conclusão

Criar um array e preenchê-lo pode ser não ser a melhor maneira de trabalhar para todos os casos, mas é importante saber como trabalhar com este tipo de estrutura.

Porém, algumas vezes o número de elementos varia, então seria melhor usar uma lista (`ArrayList`, por exemplo).

Em outras situações, a API que usamos para recuperar dados já disponibiliza formas de recuperar um array diretamente. Portanto, é imprescindível conhecer bem as APIs disponíveis no ambiente em que trabalhamos.